# Date column data being dump into excel is not formatted as a date

Tags: sql, coldfusion, spreadsheet

I am using Coldfusion and SQL to query data.

When the date columns data is dumped into Excel they are formatted as '1993-01-01 00:00:00.0'.

To format the data to MM-DD-YYYY I used:

The problem is I am unable to filter the date column in Excel by year without formatting the column to Date format.

How can I have the data column already formatted before it dumps into excel using SQL and/or Coldfusion?

Comment: Please clarify the phrase `dumped into excel` and specify your database engine.

Comment: Before it goes into Excel, make it a string with the format you're looking for. You'll possibly lose the benefits of Excel's date column, but it all depends on what you need.

Comment: use `dateformat` function when you dump the data to excel

Comment: Probably in the format you want and excel is modifying it.  Change from xls to csv for a easy test of this.